# What tool can record multiple parallel stream to files of defined size?

Tags: audio, music, recording, streaming, capture

I would like to record record multiple audio web streams like [this one](http://88.84.145.116:8000/listen.pls) in parallel to an mp3 or wma file for a duration of several days. I would like to be able to limit the file size or the duration stored in each file. The tool can be for any operating system. I do not need anything fancy like song recognition, metadata or silence detection. I haven't been able to find such a piece of software so far.

Example: 
Tap channel "News" results in:

```
News-090902-0000-0100.mp3, News-090902-0100-0200.mp3, etc...
```

Who knows what tool can do this? It can be commercial software.

Link in fulltext: 88.84.145.116:8000/listen.pls

Comment: My browser somehow escapes the colon in the link, so it doesn't work. I added it in full text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Audio Hijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/) can do this on OS X.  I've had good experiences with it.  It may not work yet on Snow Leopard.

[image]

Combining [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) with a shell script would be a multiplatform and free solution.

Comment: Hey did you manage to get Audio Hijack Pro to work on SL64? I loved this program, but it does not seem to work for me on SL64.

Comment: @scoopdreams  I'm still on 10.5.8  I didn't know there were incompatibilities. Too bad there isn't a website you could ask questions like that somewhere...  :)

Comment: -laughs- ouch, that hurts. :)

Answer (score 1):

I did that before, going on a frenzy recording several jazz web radio stations. And to do that, I run *multiple* instances of Screamer.

**[Screamer](http://www.screamer-radio.com/)**

[image]

Make sure your bandwidth can support the multiple streams though.

Comment: Screamer looks good and stable. I cannot find an option though to record raw audio only. It always splits the songs.

Answer (score 1):

I have written software that does exactly what you want, and more (if I understand correctly). It's basically a glorified front end for programs like MPlayer, VLC and such, adding some useful features.

Check it out - http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamrecnet/files/

[image]